# Can I use Restlet as a drop in replacement for Jersey?

Tags: rest, jersey, restlet

The title says it all.

I have a simple REST web service:  One class with four methods.  Three GETs and one POST.  I need a replacement for Jersey because the POST method calls a SOAP web service and that call times out.  I know the SOAP client is correct because I can run it from JUnit and JSE clients from within Eclipse.  When I run the same code from within the POST REST web service it times out.

I want to see if this happens with RESTlet.  The problem is that RESTlet doesn't forward the GET and POST requests to the methods of my Java class.

First question:  Is RESTlet JSR-339 compatible?  If not, then thanks but no thanks.  If it is then please keep reading.

Maybe I've missed something because I've had to piece together things I've found with Google since the RESTlet web site doesn't show how to migrate a Jersey REST web service to RESTlet.

Here are the changes I've made to pom.xml and web.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Catch all requests -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My web services are not being called but there is some output to the Tomcat console:

```
Jan 10, 2014 9:06:14 PM org.restlet.engine.log.LogFilter afterHandle
INFO: 2014-01-10        21:06:14        127.0.0.1       -       127.0.0.1
8080    GET     /mtprest/Product/part   partNumberPrefix=1234   404     0
0       0       http://localhost:8080   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Appl
eWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36    http://l
ocalhost:8080/mtp/indexProduct?product_param=&&searchCriteria=&&searchFlag=None&
&startRecord=1&serialNumber=localserialNumber
```

Can I use RESTlet as a drop in replacement for Jersey?  If so what do I have to do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Restlet doesn't fully support JSR-339 (JAX-RS 2.0) but most of JSR-331 (JAX-RS 1.0) spec.

Did you configure the JaxRsApplication as your ServerServlet target?
http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/snapshot/jee/ext/org/restlet/ext/jaxrs/JaxRsApplication.html

Comment: I can't think of anything within Jersey that would change the behavior of the code within your @POST method.  Given that it works from Eclipse and outside of an app server, I think it's much more likely that either 1) the SecurityManager in your app server is breaking things 2) some OS level issue is causing the timeout (SELinux, OS firewall, need to use a proxy server, etc) or 3) whatever client you're using is timing out because it isn't getting a response back from the POST quickly enough.